# nomad woes: NOMAD_IP_myport is my external interface IP, even though I'm using network.mode = "bridge"

Tags: consul, nomad

I've set up a nomad cluster on 2 VPS, one with `nomad` server, `consul` server and `vault`, and another with `nomad` and `consul` client.

On the client node I'm trying to run `nomad job`s, e.g. a `postgres` service that should be reachable by other containers on an internal network. So I chose `bridge` mode like so:

```
    group "myservices" {
        count = 1

        network {
            mode = "bridge"
            port "postgrestcp" {
                to = 5432 
            }
        }

        service {
            name = "svc-postgres"
            port = "postgrestcp"
            tags = ["postgres","primary"]
   ...
        task "task-postgres" {
            driver = "docker"

            config {
                image = "docker.io/postgres:16-alpine"
                ports = ["postgrestcp"]
            }
   ...
```

When I start the job and `exec` into the started container (`nomad exec -task task-postgres -t $(nomad job status myjob-postgres | grep -A2 Alloc | tail -n1 | awk '{ print $1 }') bash`)

I find that all relevant `NOMAD_ADDR...` env vars in the container contain my external interface IP instead of the IP of the default bridge (i.e. with the name `nomad`). That bridge exists and has an IP which I expect to find in the mentioned env vars.

```
> networkctl status nomad | grep -e Type -e '^\s*Address:'
                          Type: bridge
                       Address: 172.26.64.1
```

No matter what I try I can't get rid of `nomad` referring to the public IP. (I first thought it was because I was using the `podman` task driver before, but changing to `docker` didn't make a difference).

What's going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Nomad network specification, "bridge" network mode mean that there will be created a bridge *between the tasks* in the group. This is *not* "bridge" docker interface, it means something different. See https://developer.hashicorp.com/nomad/docs/networking#bridge-networking.

Nomad is redirecting the interface that was configured in the Nomad client service configuration. See https://developer.hashicorp.com/nomad/docs/configuration/client#host_network-block and https://developer.hashicorp.com/nomad/docs/job-specification/network#host_network . The default interface is the one used to connect, i.e. "external" one. I typically add also `host_network "lo" { interface = "lo" }` to have localhost. Consider using firewall to prevent external stuff from reaching your services. Typically, having many servers, you want it to be an external port, so that other services can reach it.

Other containers *can* connect to the service using the IP and port it was assigned to. *Within the group* in the job use `${NOMAD_ADDR_postgrescp}` to connect to it. If not within the group, i.e. from other tasks and anything else, you have to extract that information from Nomad. You can:

- register the service in consul or nomad providers, see https://developer.hashicorp.com/nomad/docs/job-specification/service

  - and generate template with configuration pointing to the service, see https://developer.hashicorp.com/nomad/docs/job-specification/template#nomad-services and https://developer.hashicorp.com/nomad/docs/job-specification/template#consul-services .
- or register the service in consul, integrate consul DNS to your system (see https://developer.hashicorp.com/consul/tutorials/networking/dns-forwarding), and integrate a proxy like fabio or traefik, see https://developer.hashicorp.com/nomad/tutorials/load-balancing/load-balancing-fabio, extract IP and port using DNS from consul

  - connect to like `postgrestcp.service.consul.your.domain.com`,
  - extract assigned service port also using DNS from consul, see https://developer.hashicorp.com/consul/docs/services/discovery/dns-static-lookups#rfc-2782-lookup .
  - note: some services support RFC 2782 DNS SRV by themselves, no idea about postgres.
- or other services could also straight interface with Nomad API to find the assigned IP and port to the service

  - something along `nomad operator api /v1/job/yourservice/allocations | jq 'filter(.Status == "running") | .[0].ID' | xargs nomad alloc status -json | jq '.Resources.Networks | <find the port with postgrestcp label>'`
  - or I created `nomad-port` part of https://pypi.org/project/nomad-tools/ that exactly does that - prints IP and port.

In our network, we have fabio & consul. For HTTP services, we just pick a name, add it to `urlprefix-name.service.consul.our.domain` to consul service tags within a job, and connect to the URL in the browser. For other services, most commonly templating is used to generate other services configuration, like airflow connecting to postgres or redis.

Comment: Thanks for the quick and elaborate reply. I'm aware that the nomad bridge != docker bridge (which is called `docker0` on my VPS), but it *is* a bridge, and it's visible with `networkctl` (under the default name `nomad` which is mentioned in the nomad docs). 

But the point is that `${NOMAD_ADDR_postgrestcp}` in my case *does not* contain a local address but the public IP, not in the container in the defining job, or other tasks in the same group.

If I query `.Resources.Networks` the item with my port in it has `"IP": "<my-ext-ip>", "Mode": "bridge"`

Comment: Yes, it is what `NOMAD_ADDR` has, it has the IP of the interface configured in Nomad service client, as explained above. You want local address on the bridge? I think it's `localhost:${NOMAD_HOST_PORT_label}` from inside the container inside the group. Try `${NOMAD_HOST_ADDR_label}`. Or you take the ip from `ip a eth0` from the container and try to connect to that ip to `NOAMD_HOST_PORT`.

Comment: That's the thing, *all* `NOMAD_HOST*` also have the external IP. And the nomad client (nomad service `bind_address`) is configured explicitly to use yet another IP, which is a private wireguard network. In other words, the documented mechanism for inter-container networking cannot work in my case, because `nomad` thinks that the containers should listen on the `host` network (even though I'm explicitly telling it not to), and therefore it sets its variables wrongly as well.

Comment: Interestingly, if I find out the actual container address it is indeed in the same subnet as `networkctl` reports for the `nomad` bridge. So somehow nomad starts the container with the correct bridge, but sets its variables incorrectly. (And sure enough, a test `nginx` container can be contacted from the client host with `curl http://<container-address>:80` but only if I find out the container address myself, `.Resources.Networks` still contains the external IP.

Comment: While it's still fuzzy, explicitly setting `nomad.client.network_interface = "wg_nomad"` (my private cluster-spanning wireguard net) in combination with `consul templates` in `nomad job specs` seems to do the job, achieving the expected: i.e. not exposing the services on the public IP and having a correct address:port reference to services. Maybe it's even "better" than getting the node-local nomad bridge addresses (nomad exposes these via `iptables` forwards to `wg_nomad`), because we now get cluster-wide accessibility of services through the wireguard private subnet...

Comment: I do not follow, and I think I am confused.  `NOMAD_HOST` and `NOMAD_ADDR` has the IP specified in Nomad client server configuration (not in the job). Nomad creates a redirection, actually docker does it using iptables, from NOMAD_ADDR -> the actual ip and port the container is running on. The same way as `docker run -p` works. This is _not_ the ip and port the service should be listening on. If you want to listen on localhost, i.e. `dokcer run -p 127.0.0.1:<host_port>:<container_port>`, specify `host_network`. I posted links above to docs in the 2nd paragraph.

Comment: Sorry, I abbreviated too much, I mean the variables which include the port label, like `NOMAD_ADDR_nginxhttp` for instance. But it's not entirely wrong, because I *can* access the service on there, but it's undesired because (obviously) I don't want to expose internal services to the public IP, but only to other services. I find it funky that [see here](https://developer.hashicorp.com/nomad/docs/configuration/client#network_interface) the default `nomad client` setting apparently does this, instead of using the actual `nomad` bridge it defines per default for container networking.

Comment: Sure. The `NOMAD_ADDR_` has `host_network` IP connected to the port, which is specified in the Nomad client service configuration, it's really unrelated to the network mode. To make Nomad client redirect a different IP, specify host_network in the Nomad service configuration /etc/nomad/nomad.yml and then in the network block in the job, see 2nd paragraph of my answer. If you do not want Nomad to redirect anything, then just remove the `port {}` from `network` block. As noted, I usually add `lo` host network to use localhost.